# Is it possible to decouple stdout and different traffic on UART in Polarfire SoC Yocto environment

Tags: serial-port, embedded, yocto, uart

I am working on a Yocto distribution for Microchip Polarfire SoC.

I would like to communicate, with a user-defined protocol, with the SoC through its UART interface, transmitting and receiving well-formatted messages. Unfortunately, the messages printed by the application (through std::cout or printf) are also redirected through the UART interface, in fact, connecting my Host PC to the board through the UART, I can read the printed messages (with putty, gtkterm, moba or whatever).

I don't think it is possible, but is there a way to "decouple" the messages to be printed over console and the messages I wish to transmit/receive over the UART?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution is to use the serial port to host a PPP (point-to-point protocol) connection to the development host, then access the shell from the host using SSH (or telnet) rather than a direct serial terminal, where `stdout` will be directed, leaving any other TCP or UDP port available for other data.

You can open multiple connections in this way, each carrying a different protocol.  The throughput will be the limiting factor of course.

If you want the UART to be for the exclusive use of your protocol, then you can simply redirect stdout to a null device or a file.  Redirecting `stderr` and `stdin` will also be required.

Alternatively of course simply configure the OS to use some other device as the default for I/O at start-up.